# Let $G$ be a group in which $(ab)^{14}=a^{14}b^{14}$ and $(ab)^{5}=a^{5}b^{5}$. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group in which $(ab)^{14}=a^{14}b^{14}$ and $(ab)^{5}=a^{5}b^{5}$ , for all $a,b\in G$. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem? If you don't show any attempt to have solved it you probably won't get any help.

Comment: by $(ab)^{14}=a^{14}b^{14}$ we get that $(ba)^{13}=a^{13}b^{13}$ and by $(ab)^5=a^{5}b^{5}$ we get that $(ba)^4=a^{4}b^{4}$ similarly we have $(ab)^{15}=b^{15}a^{15}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Compute $(ab)^{15}$ in two different ways.

Comment: I have already done it. It does not answer the question. If you claim it does so do it.

Comment: It is a way to solve the problem. If you don't get the right result show us your calculations.

Comment: @Henrik I have deduced that $(ab)^3=(ba)^3$. how can I deduce that $ab=ba$ from that?